# Long click on application icon

Tags: android

For an application I am building I am looking to have the user be able to long click the icon when starting the application. this would then bring up a menu with different options for the user. Is this possible? I have looked at the developer pages and seen ActionMode.Callback interface when discussing menus. Would this be suitable for an application icon rather than inside the application itself?

thanks.

I tried to make it work but I was getting no where, so I decided to try access the different application from within the context menu. The context_home case is not working. Could you please help.

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info;

    try {

         info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

        } catch (ClassCastException e) {

                 Log.e(TAG, "bad menuInfo", e);

                 return false;
    }

    Uri noteUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(getIntent().getData(), info.id);

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.context_open:

    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT, noteUri));

    return true;

    case R.id.context_copy:

    ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager)

    getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);

    clipboard.setPrimaryClip(ClipData.newUri(getContentResolver(),"Note",noteUri));

    return true;

    case R.id.context_delete:

    getContentResolver().delete(noteUri,null, null);

    return true;

    case R.id.context_home:

    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("project,android.project");
    startActivity(intent);
    return true;

    default:
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please be more clear on your requirements. Give a scenario you need to work on.

Comment: If you want to start the application (with the different modes, options etc.) and you want this "menu" to appear before you start the application - it's not possible in the current default mod, but maybe if you use some custom mods (or white your own) it could be achievable.

Answer (score 9):

Use [App Shortcuts](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts.html) (starting from API level 25).

- Find your main activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`
- Add reference to the resource with defined shortcuts:

  ```
  <meta-data android:name="android.app.shortcuts"
             android:resource="@xml/shortcuts" />
  ```
- Define shortcuts in referenced file:

  ```
  <shortcuts xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <shortcut
      android:shortcutId="compose"
      android:enabled="true"
      android:icon="@drawable/compose_icon"
      android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/compose_shortcut_short_label1"
      android:shortcutLongLabel="@string/compose_shortcut_long_label1"
      android:shortcutDisabledMessage="@string/compose_disabled_message1">
      <intent
        android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
        android:targetPackage="com.example.myapplication"
        android:targetClass="com.example.myapplication.ComposeActivity" />
      <!-- If your shortcut is associated with multiple intents, include them
           here. The last intent in the list determines what the user sees when
           they launch this shortcut. -->
      <categories android:name="android.shortcut.conversation" />
    </shortcut>
    <!-- Specify more shortcuts here. -->
  </shortcuts>
  ```

Answer (score 2):

If your app targets Android 7.1 (API level 25) or higher, you can define shortcuts to specific actions in your app.

Follow this : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts

Answer (score 1):

As of 2013 APIs you can't. You got no control over launcher.

**EDIT**

Android 7.1 (API 25) introduces concept of [app shortcuts](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts/), which is more less what OP formerly wanted to achieve in 2013.

[image]